# Conditional operator unary in C

Tags: c

Can anyone explain to me or tell me how to fix this coding issue i have with conditional operator

it seems to always skip the conditional operator and just print out the second option even when i change server to be 0 or 1

and it always prints out the second option SetB then SetA

why does this not work? it is some kind of semantic error? or logical error?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

   int ch = -191;
   int x = UINT_MAX;
   int setA[5]={-1,-1,-1,-1,-1};
   int setB[5]={-2,-2,-2,-2,-2};
   int server = 1;
   int i=2;

   printf("%d %d\n",server==1?setA[i],setB[i]:setB[i],setA[i]);
   printf("%d %d\n",server==0?setA[i],setB[i]:setB[i],setA[i]);


  // printf("%u\n%u\n",ch,x);

}
```

Comment: `int x = UINT_MAX` is a mistake. `int` can only hold values up to `INT_MAX`.

Comment: `server==n?setA[i],setB[i]:setB[i]` meant `server==n?setB[i]:setB[i]`

Comment: You could simply use the correct syntax for what you want to do.  I.E. rather than: printf("%d %d\n",server==1?setA[i],setB[i]:setB[i],setA[i]);  you could do: printf("%d %d\n",(server==1)?(setA[i],setB[i]):(setB[i],setA[i]));

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The grammar for the ternary operator is: *condition* ? *expression* : *expression*

In your code the first expression is `setA[i], setB[i]` and the second expression is `setB[i]`.  Due to the way the language grammar works, the final comma is an argument separator (not a part of the second *expression*), so your code is equivalent to:

```
int a = (server == 1) ? setB[i] : setB[i];
printf("%d %d\n", a, setA[i]);
```

which of course is the same as:

```
printf("%d %d\n", setB[i], setA[i]);
```

so you always get the same result regardless of the condition.

---

If you are going to have many similar lines in a block of code, one possible solution is to set up some set aliases based on the current server:

```
// do this once:
int *set0, *set1;
if ( server == 1 )
    set0 = setA, set1 = setB;
else
    set0 = setB, set1 = setA;

// then use it like this    
printf("%d %d\n", set0[i], set1[i]);
```

Comment: I can't think of an elegant way to do what you want ; a preprocessor macro has the problem that it will evaluate its argument twice; and an inline function would be cumbersome as you have to pass the arrays to it as well as your condition result

Comment: There is `if ( server == 1 ) printf("%d %d", setA[i], setB[i]); else printf("%d %d", setB[i], setA[i]);` although this doesn't scale well

Answer (score 1):

```
server==1?setA[i],setB[i]:setB[i],setA[i]
```

Note the comma operator between the conditional operator, this expression doesn't result as you expected.

Instead, I suggest using an `if` statement. It's more clear and less error-prone.

```
if (server == 1)
{
    printf("%d %d\n", setA[i], setB[i]);
}
else
{
    printf("%d %d\n", setB[i], setA[i]);
}
```

Comment: although what gets printed is the second option 

setB[i],setA[i]

Answer (score 1):

The expression

```
server==1?setA[i],setB[i]:setB[i],setA[i]
```

is equivalent to:

```
(server==1? (setA[i],setB[i]) : setB[i]), setA[i])
```

which is equivalent to

```
(server==1? setB[i] : setB[i]), setA[i]
```

which is equivalent to

```
setB[i], setA[i]
```

But, that's not what you wanted. What you wanted was:

```
if ( server == 1 )
{
  printf("%d %d\n", setA[i], setB[i]);
}
else if ( server == 0 )
{
  printf("%d %d\n", setB[i], setA[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the ternary operator like this:

`server == 1 ? printf("%d %d", setA[i], setB[i]):printf("%d %d", setB[i], setA[i]);`

and similarly for second statement.

The way you use it:

if `server == 1`
then `setA[i], setB[i]` evaluates to `setB[i]`, because that is property of comma `,` operator in C, and only the last statement is executed.

i.e.

If `server == 1`
then

`printf("%d %d\n",server==1?setA[i],setB[i]:setB[i],setA[i]);`

will be evaluated as (due to high precedence of `?:` operator over `,` operator)

`printf("%d %d\n",(server==1?(setA[i],setB[i]):setB[i]),setA[i]);`

which is

`printf("%d %d\n",setB[i], setA[i]);`

and similarly

`printf("%d %d\n",server==0?setA[i],setB[i]:setB[i],setA[i]);`

will be evaluated simply as

`printf("%d %d\n",(server==0?(setA[i],setB[i]):setB[i]),setA[i])`

which is again

`printf("%d %d\n",setB[i],setA[i]);`

You can parse similarly for `server == 0` you will get same result.